# HTML frame: "please wait" while loading

Tags: html, frames

I have very simple web page with frames. I understand frames are obsolete.

When I click on a link in the sidebar, a PHP page loads in the main frame.

```html
<a href="pageA.php" target="Frame_Main">Page A</a>
<a href="pageB.php" target="Frame_Main">Page B</a>
<a href="pageC.php" target="Frame_Main">Page C</a>
```

The pages take several seconds to load. If page A is displayed, then I click on page B, there will be no visible change, and no feedback that the click has happened, until page B is ready.

I would like, as soon as the link is clicked, to clear the main frame, and display a "please wait" sign there, while the PHP script runs. How do I do that?

I am totally open to a solution using iframes, rather than frames.

Comment: I really don't know where to start. Google is not helping, probably because frames are obsolete. I understand that asking for working code, without a starting point, may be too much. A generic description like "use the JS function XXX, then do this..." could get me started, and I could then post my final result for others to see.

Answer (score 1):

You could place the sign above the frame (using `position: fixed;`) and hide it (`display: none;`). Then make it visible as soon the link is clicked (`onclick`) and hide it, when frame has loaded (`onload`).

Here's an example:

```js
function showSpinner() {
        document.getElementById('sign').style.display = 'block';
    }
    function hideSpinner() {
        document.getElementById('sign').style.display = 'none';
    }
```

```css
#sign {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
    }
```

```html
<a href="pageA.php" target="Frame_Main" onclick="showSpinner()">Page A</a>
<a href="pageB.php" target="Frame_Main" onclick="showSpinner()">Page B</a>
<a href="pageC.php" target="Frame_Main" onclick="showSpinner()">Page C</a>

<iframe name="Frame_Main" src="pageA.php" onload="hideSpinner()">
        
</iframe>

<div id="sign">
    <img src="images/sign.png" alt="please wait" />
</div>
```

Comment: I implemented this solution, and I get the "please wait" image at the bottom of the sidebar. As expected, the image appears when the page is loading, and disappears when it finished loading. But the previously loaded page still stays in place.

Is there an easy way to add something to the showSpinner(), so that Frame_Main becomes immediately blank when the next page is loading?

Comment: You can position the 'sign'-div to exactly cover the iframe using css and give it a background-color.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `onload` method inside **iframe** element and click on aside-bar link to set attribute value of **iframe** `src` and add `active` class on `frame-wrapper` for showing **Please wait** text and when your page loaded inside iframe then `onload` method will fire and remove `active` class from `frame-wrapper`.
 Below is working snippet I hope this will help you.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(elem => {
    elem.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('wrapper').classList.add('active');
        document.getElementById('frame').setAttribute('src', e.target.href)
    })
})
```

```css
.frame-wrapper {
    width: 320px;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}
.frame-wrapper::after {
    content: attr(data-load);
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
    transition: 350ms;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.frame-wrapper.active::after {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<aside>
    <a href="pageA.php" target="Frame_Main">Page A</a>
    <a href="pageB.php" target="Frame_Main">Page B</a>
    <a href="pageC.php" target="Frame_Main">Page C</a>
</aside>
<div class="frame-wrapper active" data-load="Please wait" id="wrapper">
    <iframe src="pageA.php" id="frame" onload="document.getElementById('wrapper').classList.remove('active')" width="100%" height="220"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you done the following css approach:

```
 <div class="holds-the-iframe"><iframe here></iframe></div>
    
    .holds-the-iframe {
      background:url(../images/loader.gif) center center no-repeat;
    }
```